# Switch even, odd in list order

Tags: html, css

I am facing an issue with html element "li". On computer page everything looks perfect, but in mobile view I see the elements changes its orders as you can see in the picture. How to achieve the same result on mobile? Like I do not need to have two columns, but I want to have one with all elements in right order. Can I somehow use EVEN, ODD?

PC (ok): [image]

Mobile (bad):
[image]

```
 <ul class="list">
            <li class="mr10"><span>1.</span>reason</li>
            <li><span>4.</span>reason</li>
            <li class="mr10"><span>2.</span>reason</li>
            <li><span>5.</span>reason</li>
            <li class="mr10"><span>3.</span>reason</li> 
            <li><span>6.</span>reason</li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.list{
    margin:0 0 35px 0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
 ul.list li{
    line-height:45px;
    margin:10px 0;
    font-size:24px;
    border:1px solid #111a23;
    padding:10px 0 10px 10px;
     float:left;
     width:49%;
}
 ul.list li.mr10{
    margin-right:2%
}
 ul.list li span{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:24px;
    background:#ff9900;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    line-height:45px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:20px;
    color:#000;
     border-radius: 50px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
     -moz-border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the order via css, or do I need to change the whole order in html?

Comment: You should have your list items in the _correct_ order in the HTML to begin with; and then use Column Layout in CSS, to get the view you want on desktop. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Column_layouts

Comment: You can do it using flex box in mobile by setting flex-flow to column and changing the order of your elements as you like ( you can use :nth-child() selector for ordering)